# validation and train metrics very low values (images and masks generator)

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have images(X_train) and masks data (y_train).

I want to train a unet network. I am currently using iou metric and the validation iou is very low and constant!

I am not sure if I can handle right the scaling preprocessing of images and masks.

I have tried either to use only `rescale=1.0/255` in the generator, either to scale only `X_train` and `X_val` hence `(images)` values and not `masks` values, either scale in the unet model `(s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0) (inputs))` . I am not sure if that is the problem, just wondering.

[here](https://easyupload.io/m/u7t5yl) you can download `X_train` and `y_train` data

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,  MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose, \
    Dropout, Input, Concatenate, Lambda
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K


# gpu setup
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    

X_train = np.load('./X_train.npy')
y_train = np.load('/y_train.npy')


X_train = X_train.astype('uint8')
y_train = y_train.astype('uint8')


BATCH_SIZE=8
SEED=123
VAL_SPLIT = 0.2
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
IMG_WIDTH = 256

def augment(images):

    seq =  iaa.Sequential([
        
        iaa.Fliplr(0.5), # horizontal flips
        iaa.Flipud(0.5), # vertical flips
       
        iaa.Sometimes(
             0.1,
             iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0, 0.5))
        ),
        iaa.LinearContrast((0.75, 1.5)),
       
        iaa.Sharpen(alpha=(0, 1.0), lightness=(0.75, 1.5)),
              
        iaa.BlendAlphaSimplexNoise(
            iaa.EdgeDetect(0.3),
            upscale_method="linear"),
        
       
        
    ], random_order=True) 
    
    return seq.augment_image(images)


def create_gen(X,
               y,
               batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
               seed=SEED):
    
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = \
        train_test_split(X,
                         y,
                         test_size=VAL_SPLIT)
        
    
    # Image data generator
    data_gen_args = dict(rescale = 1.0/255,
                         preprocessing_function=augment)

    data_gen_args_masks = dict(                      preprocessing_function=augment)
                             
    X_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    y_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args_masks)
    
    X_datagen.fit(X_train, augment=True, seed=seed)
    y_datagen.fit(y_train, augment=True, seed=seed)
    
    X_train_augmented = X_datagen.flow(X_train,
                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                       shuffle=True,
                                       seed=seed)
    y_train_augmented = y_datagen.flow(y_train,
                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                       shuffle=True,
                                       seed=seed)
    
    # Validation data generator     
    data_gen_args_val = dict(rescale = 1.0/255)
                                                     
    X_datagen_val = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args_val)
    y_datagen_val = ImageDataGenerator()
    
    X_datagen_val.fit(X_val, augment=True, seed=seed)
    y_datagen_val.fit(y_val, augment=True, seed=seed)
    
    X_val_after = X_datagen_val.flow(X_val,
                                     batch_size=batch_size,
                                     shuffle=False)
                                    
    y_val_after = y_datagen_val.flow(y_val,
                                     batch_size=batch_size,
                                     shuffle=False)
                                    
     
    train_generator = zip(X_train_augmented, y_train_augmented)
    val_generator = zip(X_val_after, y_val_after)
    
    steps_per_epoch = X_train_augmented.n // X_train_augmented.batch_size
    validation_steps = X_val_after.n // X_val_after.batch_size
    return train_generator, val_generator, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps


train_generator, val_generator, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps =  \
    create_gen(X_train,
               y_train,
               batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)


# Build U-Net model
inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3))
#s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)  # rescale inputs

c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (inputs)
c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p2)
c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c3)
p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p3)
c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c4)
p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p4)
c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c5)

u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
u6 = Concatenate()([u6, c4])
c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u6)
c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c6)

u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
u7 = Concatenate()([u7, c3])
c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u7)
c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c7)

u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
u8 = Concatenate()([u8, c2])
c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u8)
c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c8)

u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
u9 = Concatenate()([u9, c1])
c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)

outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[iouMetric])

EPOCHS = 40

model.fit( train_generator,
           validation_data=val_generator,
           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
           steps_per_epoch= steps_per_epoch,
           validation_steps=validation_steps,
 epochs=EPOCHS)
```

code for ioumetric:

```
def castF(x):
    return K.cast(x, K.floatx())

def castB(x):
    return K.cast(x, bool)

def iou_loss_core(true,pred):  #this can be used as a loss if you make it negative
    intersection = true * pred
    notTrue = 1 - true
    union = true + (notTrue * pred)

    return (K.sum(intersection, axis=-1) + K.epsilon()) / (K.sum(union, axis=-1) + K.epsilon())

def iouMetric(true, pred):

    tresholds = [0.5 + (i * 0.05)  for i in range(5)]

    #flattened images (batch, pixels)
    true = K.batch_flatten(true)
    pred = K.batch_flatten(pred)
    pred = castF(K.greater(pred, 0.5))

    #total white pixels - (batch,)
    trueSum = K.sum(true, axis=-1)
    predSum = K.sum(pred, axis=-1)

    #has mask or not per image - (batch,)
    true1 = castF(K.greater(trueSum, 1))    
    pred1 = castF(K.greater(predSum, 1))

    #to get images that have mask in both true and pred
    truePositiveMask = castB(true1 * pred1)

    #separating only the possible true positives to check iou
    testTrue = tf.boolean_mask(true, truePositiveMask)
    testPred = tf.boolean_mask(pred, truePositiveMask)

    #getting iou and threshold comparisons
    iou = iou_loss_core(testTrue,testPred) 
    truePositives = [castF(K.greater(iou, tres)) for tres in tresholds]

    #mean of thressholds for true positives and total sum
    truePositives = K.mean(K.stack(truePositives, axis=-1), axis=-1)
    truePositives = K.sum(truePositives)

    #to get images that don't have mask in both true and pred
    trueNegatives = (1-true1) * (1 - pred1) # = 1 -true1 - pred1 + true1*pred1
    trueNegatives = K.sum(trueNegatives) 

    return (truePositives + trueNegatives) / castF(K.shape(true)[0])
```

I tried other metrics as well, dice loss is also constant and very low. Accuracy is around 79 and constant.

Comment: I am not sure what type of dataset you have but try to remove destructive augmentation. Also, just a suggestion but look into the `segmentation_models` library. This will make things a lot more easier and the code a lot more compact.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the pre-processing. According to [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) documentation:

> preprocessing_function: function that will be applied on each input. The function will run **after** the image is resized and augmented. The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape.

So, this function will run additionally *after* the augmentation you mentioned inside `ImageDataGenerator`. But the problem is that you already have scaled the images with `1.0 / 255`, so, the `augment()` function is getting a scaled image. But according to the documentation of [imgaug](https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/examples_basics.html#a-standard-use-case), it wants an un-scaled image (see the comment inside the example):

> 'images' should be either a 4D numpy array of shape (N, height, width, channels)
> or a list of 3D numpy arrays, each having shape (height, width, channels).
> Grayscale images must have shape (height, width, 1) each.
> All images must have numpy's dtype uint8. Values are expected to be in
> range **0-255**.

**Edit**:
In the output you are using `sigmoid` activation function. Which will force the output to be always within `[0, 1]`. But you are not scaling the mask, that means the mask will be within `[0, 255]`. So, for obvious reason, the model will never be able output these large values, as it is restricted to be within `[0, 1]`. So, remove the `sigmoid` from the last layer and see what happens.

Comment: @George I have updated my answer. I couldn't manage to download the data and run it myself, as the downloading was terminating so often. But I found an inconsistency by skimming through your code.

Comment: I tried it but still the same..I tried also to scale while training `s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)  # rescale inputs`.. Thanks.

Comment: @George Probably I couldn't make the point clear to you. What I was saying, in `y_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args_masks)` you are not scaling `y_datagen`. But in `outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)` you are using sigmoid function which will scale the output within `[0, 1]`. So, just remove `sigmoid` activation from here, because your `outputs` from the model (not talking about `inputs`) are supposed to unscaled as you are fitting with unscaled data wrt. output end (but for `sigmoid` it is forcefully being scaled from the model).

Comment: Or, if you want to keep sigmoid, then scale all outputs with `1.0/255` (train and validation both) as well.

Comment: I have tried this also..I have tried every combination without success!